# If $\sum a_n$ converges, so does $\sum a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a positive real sequence such that the series $\sum a_n$ converges.

I was asked to prove that under such circumstances $\sum a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ converges.

The previous sum can be rewritten as $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_n^{1/(n+1)}}$.

I can't prove the convergence of this last series... I'm sure comparison test is enough here, but other than $a_n \rightarrow 0$ there is no information that helps.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

If $a_n \le \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, then $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\le \frac{1}{2^n}$.

If $a_n \gt  \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, then by your calculation $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\le 2a_n$.

Thus for all $n$ we have $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\le \frac{1}{2^n}+2a_n$.

Let $b_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+2a_n$. Then $\sum b_n$ converges, and therefore by Comparison so does our sum.

Comment: Well that works, but how did you have the idea to check whether $a_n \leq 1/2^{n+1}$ or not ?

Comment: Well, I looked at your expression, and noticed it is helpful if $a_n^{1/(n+1)}$ is not too small, but not helpful if $a_n^{1/(n+1)}$ is close to $0$. However, if that happens, then $a_n$ is small, so things are good then also. The rest was mechanical.

Answer (score 7):

We have that by AM-GM

$$a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\le \frac{2a_n+2a_n+\ldots+2a_n+\frac1{2^n}}{n+1}=\frac{2na_n+\frac1{2^n}}{n+1} \le2a_n+\frac1{2^n}$$

Comment: Nice application of the AM-GM (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks! At first I tried with $na_n+1$ then with $a_n+2a_n+\ldots+na_n+\frac1{n!}$ and finally I had the ispiration from the answer by Mindlack to try with that.

Comment: Of course the number $2$ is not a magic number here.  And I'm not sure the reason for choosing it.  One could have said for any $C>1$, $a_n^{n/(n+1)}\le \frac{Cna_n+\frac1{C^n}}{n+1}$

Comment: @MarkViola Yes of course, any $C>1$ works fine!

Comment: @MarkViola What is the asymptotic for $a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, and
set $$S=\big\{n: a_n^{n/(n+1)}\le 2a_n\big\},$$ and $$T=\big\{n: a_n^{n/(n+1)}> 2a_n\big\}.$$

If $n\in T$, then 
$$
a^{n/(n+1)}_n> 2a_n\quad\Longrightarrow\quad a_n^n>2^{n+1}a_n^{n+1}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
a_n<2^{-n-1}.
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{n/(n+1)}_n=
\sum_{n\in S} a^{n/(n+1)}_n+\sum_{n\in T} a^{n/(n+1)}_n\le 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-1}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{n/(n+1)}_n\le
\frac{1}{2}+2A<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $a_n \leq 2^{-n-1}$, then $a_n^{n/(n+1)} \leq 2^{-n}$. Otherwise, $a_n^{n/(n+1)} \leq 2a_n$.