# If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ converges as well.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

If $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges, then show that $\sum a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ converges as well.

Attempt:

We try to apply the Limit form of the Comparison Test here.

We note, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{\frac{n}{n+1}} =a_n$

Now, comparing the two series, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n)^{\frac{n}{n+1}}}{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n}=1$.

Therefore, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum a^{n/(n+1)}$ converges as well.

I have a feeling that I have made a mistake somewhere. I am doubtful about the application of the comparison test in this case.

Can anyone kindly correct/verify it?

Duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148745/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-then-so-does-sum-n-1-infty-a-n?rq=1).

Comment: One small thing: writing $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{n/(n+1)} = a_n$ does not make sense (you take the limit on the left so the result cannot depend on $n$ the variable you take the limit over). What you mean to say is that $a_n^{n/(n+1)}$ behaves as $a_n$ as $n\to\infty$ (which you do in the next line). A common notation for this is to write $a_n^{n/(n+1)} \sim a_n$ which means that the limit of the ratio of the left and right hand side is unity.

Comment: yes! Can this be called an "abuse of notation"? Does the answer hold good after correcting the mistake?

Comment: I am concerned about two things here: 
1. Notational mistake 
2. Rigorousness of the proof itself.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas I will rather say that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{{a_n}^{\frac{n}{n+1}}}{a_n}=1$

Comment: There's no reason to think that this limit exists and equals $1$

Comment: @John.P , is that going to be perfectly fine/valid?

Comment: @Jakobian, for example?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas $a_n = 2^{-n^2}$.

Comment: @Jakobian , excellent! Now I have to discard this "Proof".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678628/if-sum-a-n-converges-so-does-sum-a-n-fracnn1?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148745/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-then-so-does-sum-n-1-infty-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BarzanHayati awesome!

Comment: I am talking about the answer that uses $a_n<1/2$.... I should have checked more of the related questions.. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\sum a_n$ converges, so does $\sum a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678628/if-sum-a-n-converges-so-does-sum-a-n-fracnn1)